# html- can you change the end tag?

Tags: html, multiple-browsers

Do all browsers support using different end tags?

For example:

```
<p> hello </p value='f'>
```

or

```
<p> hello </p hello_end>
```

Comment: Yes. But why would you want to do this? The "attributes" will just be thrown away by the browser.

Comment: Have a look at the [HTML syntax at W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#end-tags) - > end tag definition: The next few characters of an end tag must be the element's tag name.

Comment: The term "all browsers" is very misleading. Define the browsers you actually intend to support and test.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This makes no sense.

Comment: Its for marking end tags for javascript

Comment: And what does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you may be a HTML newbie

As mentioned by Pasty

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#end-tags

HTML Standard is having attribute value pairs in the starting tag like

```
<p attr='value'>
```

and not at the end tags

Even if you place some value those will be ignored.

Comment: I dont care that they will be ignore. I just want to mark those end tags for later use.

Comment: yeah, you can put.It will be better if you can mention why you want that, so that we can help for use case